# Product sigma algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it true that, if $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{-\infty\}$,

$$D=\bar{\mathbb{R}}\times\cdots\times(b_j,\infty]\times\cdots\times\bar{\mathbb{R}}\in\sigma\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,\infty]\right)?$$

I have tried finding some $A$ such that $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^n\backslash A = D$ and hope that $A\in\sigma\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i,\infty]\right)$ but failed.

Comment: Is $-\infty \in \bar{\Bbb R}$?

Comment: Yes, here $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}\cup\{-\infty\}$.